# Add line between XML elements: Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am creating XML elements and prettyprinting it like shown:

```
rootElement = Element("root)
childElement = SubElement(rootElement, "child")
def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
print prettify(rootElement)
```

The output looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <child/>
</root>
```

How can i add additional lines between these elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
 <!-- how to add line spaces here -->
  <child/>
</root>
```

Comment: The new lines has no meaning in XML and therefore there is no support for adding new line between element X and element Y

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation states

> `Node.toprettyxml(indent="\t", newl="\n", encoding=None)`

The `newl` parameter handles the line spacing. So you can give single or multiple line spaces to do this.

Comment: But i need it for a particular element before printing. Like shown in the question, I wanted that line between root and child element.